# Spring MVC form not backed by a model object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am pretty new to Spring MVC so please be easy on me.

I am having difficulties to understand how to achieve the following requirements in Spring MVC:

- JSP list form, to list users from the database (service, repository thing are working properly).
- Form is not backed by a model attribute object. This is a list/find form!
- I need to list users matching some criteria taken from several "filter" fields like:

  - Region (dropdown list)
  - Is user archived? (yes/no dropdown list)

userList.jsp

```
<spring:url value="strFormAction" var="/rest/security/user/list" />
<form:form id="userListForm" method="GET" action="${strFormAction}" modelAttribute="user">

<form:select id="strRegionId" path="${strRegionId}" cssClass="form-control" onchange="updateUsersList('1');">
    <spring:message var="strSelectRegionLabel" code="select.region" />                          
    <form:option value="0" label="${strSelectRegionLabel}" />
    <form:options items="${regions}" itemValue="intId" itemLabel="strNameFr" />
</form:select>

<form:select id="strArchived" path="${strArchived}" cssClass="form-control">
    <spring:message var="strYesLabel" code="yes" />
    <form:option value="true" label="${strYesLabel}"/>

    <spring:message var="strNoLabel" code="no" />
    <form:option value="false" label="${strNoLabel}"/>
</form:select>

<table>

...

<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
...rows generated here...
</c:forEach>
 ...
</table>

</form:form>
```

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processUserList(  @ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
                                @RequestParam(value = "strRegionId", required = false) String strRegionId,
                                @RequestParam(value = "strArchived", required = false) String strArchived,
                                @RequestParam(value = "strSortBy", required = false) String strSortBy,
                                Model model) {

    int intRegionId = strRegionId != null && strRegionId.equals("0") == false ? Integer.valueOf(strRegionId) : 0;
    boolean booArchived = strArchived != null && strArchived.length() > 0 ? Boolean.valueOf(strArchived) : false;       
    int intSortBy = strSortBy != null && strSortBy.length() > 0 ? Integer.valueOf(strSortBy) : 1;

    List<Region> regions = this.locationService.lstRegions();
    model.addAttribute("strRegionId", String.valueOf(intRegionId));
    model.addAttribute("strArchived", String.valueOf(booArchived));
    model.addAttribute("strSortBy", String.valueOf(intSortBy));

    List<User> users = this.securityService.listUsersByRegionAndArchiveState(intRegionId, booArchived, intSortBy);

    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    model.addAttribute("regions", regions);

    return "user/userList";
}
```

It seems like I can't use the Spring form taglib at all without providing a modelAttribute in the form. I have then placed a dummy modelAttribute from my controller, but now I get:

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property '0' of bean class [spring4base.model.security.User]: Bean property '0' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

As I said earlier, that page is not meant to be backed by any specific POJO. This is a search page, that must return a list of users (User entity bean) based on filters selected previously (region, archived state). Form must submit on itself every time a dropdown is changed (user chooses a region, submit is done on the same mapping, and then the users list reloads with only users from that specific region).

I'm coming from Struts 1 in which we needed to create ActionForm for every single page. From what I read from the documentation, forms are not necessary these days so I am really looking forward into fixing that issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just create helper class containing your search criteria, for instance:

```
public class UserSearchCriteria {
    private String regionId;
    private Boolean archived;
    private String sortBy;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Then I would modify your controller method like so (some code is missing, but this should give you the idea).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processUserList(@ModelAttribute("searchCriteria") UserSearchCriteria userSearchCriteria, Model model) {
    // Retrieve users and perform filtering based on search criteria
    List<User> users = this.securityService.listUsers(searchCriteria);

    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    model.addAttribute("regions", regions);

    return "user/userList";
}
```

And then you would use your filtering form like this:

```
<spring:url value="/rest/security/user/list" var="formAction" />
<form:form id="userListForm" method="GET" action="${formAction}" modelAttribute="searchCriteria">

<form:select path="regionId" cssClass="form-control" onchange="updateUsersList('1');">
    <spring:message var="strSelectRegionLabel" code="select.region" />                          
    <form:option value="0" label="${strSelectRegionLabel}" />
    <form:options items="${regions}" itemValue="intId" itemLabel="strNameFr" />
</form:select>

<form:select path="archived" cssClass="form-control">
    <spring:message var="strYesLabel" code="yes" />
    <form:option value="true" label="${strYesLabel}"/>

    <spring:message var="strNoLabel" code="no" />
    <form:option value="false" label="${strNoLabel}"/>
</form:select>
```

You had several errors in the form in your snippet. For example the `path` attribute takes String containing name (or path) of the property to bind to, you were passing it some variable. Also you had `value` and `var` switched in your `<spring:url>` I think.

Try it, it's not complete solution but hopefully it will give you some directions on how to implement this. If you run into any problems, leave a comment and I'll update the answer.

Comment: That answer is one of a kind. That works like a charm. Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: What do you mean by moving the filtering logic to the service/repository layer? User must have the ability to choose the sorting option from the datagrid (users list). Let's say he clicks on the "First Name" table header, the query must be toggle sorting order on the first name. Do you mean that I should create several small methods like "listUsersSortedByFirstName", that would all use the same private method in the end? Any advice from your part would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah now that I'm looking at it you were probably doing the filtering on your service layer all along. I wrote it in kind of a hurry and by looking at the controller method I probably thought that you were filtering it on controller. Anyways I would just create one `listUsers()` method on your service and pass it the search criteria object, that might be the cleanest solution. I'll remove the unrelevant part from the answer ...

Comment: That is what I have done. My service method receives an instance of my UserSearchCriteria. That makes my controller look very lean, which is great. Thanks again!

Comment: Now what if I had a modelObject, let's say you find the user, and then a save button is available at the bottom. Can Spring have multiple modelAttributes (user pojo and the usersearchcriteria object)? I guess I would need to create another helper class, that would have a User object attribute along with the UserSearchCriteria object attribute. Am I right?

Comment: Not sure I understand completely. You want a search form and if you find a user using the search you want to have a form to edit that user? If so I would just create two separate forms, one for search (modelAttribute would be searchCriteria) and one for the user (modelAttribute would be the user).

Comment: This is for a "Add User" page. Application admin is typing a user Id in a textbox, clicks search (query is executed in Active Directory, returning all personal information for the user that is being searched), select some other stuffs that are not in Active Directory, and then click Save. That would be like a "find" page, with the ability to persist data based on the search. By "two separate forms", you mean two JSPs/views, or you would implement two <form:form /> in the same JSP?

Comment: I meant two `<form:form>` on the same page. If your search returns either zero or one user (based on that you're searching by ID) it shouldn't be a problem. But this is probably out of scope of this question. If you want to help with this, create a new question and let's solve it there so we don't spam the comments section here :)